# How to chain a series of functions which return promises, and require different parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have two asynchronous functions, which use parameters already acquired somehow:

```
var a = getUserinput();
var b = getUserinput();
var c = getUserinput();
var d = getUserinput();


var func1 = function(valA, valB){
     var deferred = $q.deferred;
     //http call with valA, valb...
     // when complete, resolve deferred
     return deferred.promise;
}

var func2 = function(valC, valD){
     var deferred = $q.deferred;
     //http call with valC, valD...
     // when complete, resolve deferred
     return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to execute `func1` and then `func2`. The problem is that I can't find a way to do this successfully while being able to provide parameters to `func2`.

For example, if I do

```
func1(a, b).then(func2(c, d));
```

`func2` executes before `func1` is done.

How do I execute `func2` only after `func1` is done?

`func`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide anonymous function and place `func2` invocation in it:

```
func1(a, b).then(function() {
    func2(c, d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I recently took the first release of the rogue written for UNIX in C and rewrote it for javascript to work in a browser.  I used a technic called continuation to be able to wait for key entry by the user because in javascript the are no interrupts.

So I would have a piece of code like this:

```
void function f() {

  // ... first part

  ch = getchar();

  // ... second part

}
```

that would be transformed in

```
function f() {

  // ... first part

  var ch = getchar(f_cont1);

  return;
  // the execution stops here 

  function f_cont1 () {

    // ... second part
  }
}
```

the continuation is then stored to be reuse on a keypressed event.  With closures everything would be restarted where it stoped.

Comment: `first release of the rogue written for UNIX in C` what does that mean?

Comment: Rogue is a text RPG game like Hangbang.